# Automatically refresh external text file in excel every second

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am using this code is excels visual basic to refresh the sheet with the external text file every second:

```
Sub AutoRefresh()

' to run a Refresh All on the workbook every n minutes

   RefreshAllDataConn

   ' Repeat every minute or change to whatever value you prefer.

   Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "AutoRefresh"


' this is a simple example. There's no coded way to exit this function.

End Sub
```

I got it from this link: https://office-watch.com/2020/excel-automatic-refresh-recalculation-tricks/ .

However, it is still only refreshing at only 1 min.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your code should run `AutoRefresh` 1 second after `RefreshAllDataConn` finishes and therefore, depends on how fast/slow `RereshAllDataConn` is

Comment: To get an idea of how long `RefreshAllDataConn` takes to run, you can add something like `Dim dStart As Double: dStart = Timer` before your call to `RefreshAllDataConn` and `MsgBox Format(Timer - dStart, "0.000")` after it

Comment: Ah got it, thanks a lot for the help!!!!!